# Array destructuring is not working with parameters to a function

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm learning TypeScript so please accept my apologies for asking a dumb question.

The following code is taken from the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html), but it is not working. It looks like the function is expecting a `Tuple` of two `number`s instead of `Array`, but on the other hand it should demonstrate Array destructuring according to the docs...

```
let input = [1, 2];
function f([first, second]: [number, number]) {
    console.log(first);
    console.log(second);
}
f(input);
```

The error:

```
src/main.ts(6,3): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.
  Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the example is indeed wrong or obsolete, or maybe it's a bug in typescript compiler. You are right, `[number, number]` is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), and the type of `input` is inferred to be `number[]`, that is, the length of array is not preserved in the type, and you get error message because `f` expects an array of exactly 2 elements.

If you call `f` with literal array it will work

```
f([1, 2]); // ok
```

You can also make it work if you declare argument as array:

```
let input: number[] = [1, 2];
function f([first, second]: number[]) {
    console.log(first);
    console.log(second);
}

f(input);
```

but it will not be checking array length that way, these calls would compile too:

```
f([]);
f([1, 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

@gamliela, to add a variation to @artem 's response, it's best to properly define the tuple type in first place:

```
let input:[number,number] = [1, 2];
let [first, second] = input;
```

As such the TS2345 warning for:

```
f(input)
```

will disappear.

Note, if you copy the doc example as-is to the playground, it shows the same TS2345 warning unless you add the proper tuple type definitions above.